# Amazon ECS agent on ubuntu not starting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I am currently trying to build a custom ubuntu ami for AWS batch and following the document mentioned here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html

However when I try to start the docker agent on that machine it always keeps giving me this error

```
2018-07-04T23:34:01Z [INFO] Amazon ECS agent Version: 1.18.0, Commit: c0defea9
2018-07-04T23:34:01Z [INFO] Loading state! module="statemanager"
2018-07-04T23:34:01Z [INFO] Event stream ContainerChange start listening...
2018-07-04T23:34:01Z [INFO] Creating root ecs cgroup: /ecs
2018-07-04T23:34:01Z [INFO] Creating cgroup /ecs
2018-07-04T23:34:01Z [WARN] Disabling TaskCPUMemLimit because agent is unabled to setup '/ecs' cgroup: cgroup create: unable to create controller: mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/ecs: read-only file system
2018-07-04T23:34:01Z [WARN] Error getting valid credentials (AKID ): NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
    For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
2018-07-04T23:34:01Z [INFO] Registering Instance with ECS
2018-07-04T23:34:01Z [ERROR] Could not register: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
    For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
2018-07-04T23:34:01Z [ERROR] Error registering: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

I made sure the instance has the ecsInstanceRole associated with that.
Can you guys let me know what I am missing?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Not certain how you are starting the ecs-agent. Ran into the error of

```
Disabling TaskCPUMemLimit because agent is unabled to setup '/ecs cgroup: cgroup create: unable to create controller: /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/ecs: read-only file system
```

We resolved this by adding the volume `--volume=/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro` to the systemd unit file that we having launching ecs.

Outside of that, I assume the issue resides with the `ecsInstanceRole`. Can you verify it has the following permissions? `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess`, `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceFullAccess`, `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role`

Below is the full systemd file for ecs-agent.

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Container %I
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm -f %i
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name %i \
--restart=on-failure:10 \
--volume=/var/run:/var/run \
--volume=/var/log/ecs/:/log:Z \
--volume=/var/lib/ecs/data:/data:Z \
--volume=/etc/ecs:/etc/ecs \
--volume=/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
--net=host \
--env-file=/etc/ecs/ecs.config \
--env LOGSPOUT=ignore \
amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop %i

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: Hi, I had the same issue and followed your steps, and got a new error: 
`level=warn time=2020-11-25T11:01:59Z msg="App: task from state file is not compatible with TaskCPUMemLimit setting, because it is not using ecs' cgroup hierarchy: arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:878038228002:task/ecs-application-cluster/919b61d3ca384c37a3ed4a3de159994a" module=agent_compatibility_linux.go` and `level=warn time=2020-11-25T11:01:59Z msg="App: disabling TaskCPUMemLimit." module=agent_compatibility_linux.go`

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: I had been only editing & restarting the ecs service which resulted in the warning posted above. I changed the source, rebuild & deployed it, and the error is gone. Could have been some caching issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same messages. You need to create the IAM role and launch the instance with that role, per this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html